# storing weight in a database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I am playing around with learning MVC and want to create a recipe recorder application to store my recipes.

I am using .net with Sql Server 2008 R2 however I don't think that really matters with what I am trying to do.

I want to be able to record all of the measures I use. In my country we use metric however I want people to be able to use imperial with my application.

How do I structure my table to cope with the differences, I was thinking of storing all of the measurements as ints and have a foreign key to store the kind of weight.

Ideally I would like to be able to share the recipes between people and display the measurements in their preferred way.

Is this the right kind of way

```
IngredientID PK
Weight int
TypeOfWeight int e.g. tsp=1,tbl=2,kilogram=3,pound=4,litre=5,ounce=6 etc
UserID int
```

Or is this way off track? Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: You should get away from calling them weights as well. Litre is a volume, as is teaspoon and tablespoon. I would just call them units of measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are storing weights (a non-discrete value) I would strongly suggest using numeric or decimal for this data.  You have the right idea with the `typeofweight` column.  Store a reference table somewhere showing what the conversion ratio is for each (to a certain standard).

This gets quite tricky when you want to show ounces as TSP, because the conversion depends on the ingredient itself, so you need a 3rd table - ingredient: id, name, volume-to-weight ratio.

Example typeofweight table, where the `standard` unit is grams

```
type   | conversion
gram   | 1
ounce  | 28.35
kg     | 1000
tsp    | 5            // assuming that 1 tsp = 5 grams of water
pound  | 453.59
```

Example ingredient volume to weight conversion

```
type   | vol-to-weight
water  | 1
sugar  | 1.4          // i.e. 1 tsp holds 5g of water, but 7g of sugar
```

So to display 500 ounces of sugar in `tsp`, you would use the formula

```
  units x ounce.conversion x sugar.vol-to-weight
= 500   x 28.35            x 1.4
```

Another example with 2 weights

```
Ingredient is specified as 3 ounces of starch.  Show in grams
= 3 x 28.35    (straightforward isn't it)
```

or

```
Ingredient is specified as 3 ounces of starch.  Show in pounds
= 3 * 28.35 / 453.59
```

Comment: thanks cyberkiwi! that helps me :) I just wish everyone used metric! I think I will be ok with things like tsp and tbl as I think that would still make sense for a person using metric to use a tsb of baking powder in a recipe. Things like a pinch of salt I dont really have to worry about converting so I should be good. Thanks again

Comment: `wet your hands under the tap`. `fling twice into the frying pan` .. convert _that_ to tsp

Answer (score 6):

I think you should store the weights (Kilo/Pound) etc as a single weight type (metric) and simply "display" them in the correct conversion using the user's preference. If the user has there weight settings set to Imperial, values entered into the system would need to be converted as well. This should simplify your data anyway.

Similar to Dates, you could store every date and what timezone it is from, or otherwise store all dates as the same (or no timezone) and then display them in the application using offsets according to the user's preference

Comment: The issue with this is that 1 ounce = 28.3495231 grams and 28 grams becomes 0.987670935 ounces.  How do you avoid or deal with rounding errors when storing all measurements in a unified weight?

Comment: @ben the unit of measure and level of accuracy needs to be decided upon appropriate to the situation and a suitable data type used